# Why does this allocate on the stack instead of the heap?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Edit: My original question is no longer accurate, so I rewrote it.

So I'm writing a program to demonstrate a heap spray in C (which I know is unusual). I'm allocating a huge buffer (100MB) using malloc, but it allocates into a segment marked mapped rather than [heap] and I can't figure out why.

My code:

```
int NOPSize = 960;
int ShellcodeSize = 64;
int PayloadSize = NOPSize + ShellcodeSize;
char Payload[PayloadSize];
char* HeapBuf = (char*)malloc(0x6400000);   //104,857,600 (100MB)

for (int x = 0; x < PayloadSize; x++)
    Payload[x] = (x <= NOPSize) ? '\x90' : '\x41';

for (int x = 0; x < 0x6400000; x++)
    HeapBuf[x] = Payload[x % PayloadSize];

printf("%x\n", HeapBuf);
free(HeapBuf);
```

Output of vmmap using GDB-PEDA taken from a breakpoint set at the call to `free` :

```
0x80000000 0x80001000 r-xp  /root/Documents/a.out
0x80001000 0x80002000 r--p  /root/Documents/a.out
0x80002000 0x80003000 rw-p  /root/Documents/a.out
0x80003000 0x80024000 rw-p  [heap]
0xb19fd000 0xb7dfe000 rw-p  mapped
0xb7dfe000 0xb7faf000 r-xp  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
0xb7faf000 0xb7fb1000 r--p  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
0xb7fb1000 0xb7fb2000 rw-p  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
0xb7fb2000 0xb7fb5000 rw-p  mapped
0xb7fd4000 0xb7fd7000 rw-p  mapped
0xb7fd7000 0xb7fd9000 r--p  [vvar]
0xb7fd9000 0xb7fdb000 r-xp  [vdso]
0xb7fdb000 0xb7ffd000 r-xp  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
0xb7ffe000 0xb7fff000 r--p  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
0xb7fff000 0xb8000000 rw-p  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
0xbffdf000 0xc0000000 rw-p  [stack]
```

`printf` outputs `0xb19fd008` which is in the top mapped segment.

Interestingly enough, the `[heap]` segment disappears if I remove the call to `printf`. So my questions, why is the presence of the `[heap]` segment dependent on the call to `printf` and why is the printed address in the mapped segment and not in the `[heap]` segment? Thanks.

Comment: What do the memory maps look like *before* the `free(HeapBuf)`?

Comment: This is before the free. It's taken from a breakpoint right before `free` executes.

Comment: You appear to be running your desktop as `root`.  Don't do that.

Comment: Please post a *complete program* that we can run for ourselves.  It would also be useful to see the *complete and unedited* output of `strace ./a.out`, but that may be so long that you shouldn't try to put it in the question.

Comment: @Cryptomancer: Could you compile and run my test program, and post the results (or your findings) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two things going on here, and before I get into them, I have to warn you that based on the presence of the string `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so` in your map output, I am deducing that the operating system you're running your program on uses the Linux kernel and the GNU C Library ('glibc').  Some of what I'm about to tell you is very particular to those components.

First: for historical reasons, there are two different ways to allocate memory on operating systems that qualify as "Unix" (to first order: everything anyone still uses, except Windows): the system calls [`sbrk`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk) and [`mmap`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap).  `sbrk` is much more limited; it can only manage the *size* of a single region of memory at a predetermined location, whereas `mmap` (and its counterpart `munmap`) can allocate and deallocate independent blocks of memory anywhere in the address space. Linux's `/proc/PID/maps` file uses the `[heap]` label for the memory region managed by `sbrk`. Independent blocks of memory allocated with `mmap` are labeled "mapped".

Second: glibc's implementation of `malloc` uses `sbrk` for small allocations and `mmap` for large allocations (see the discussion of `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD` in the [`mallopt` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mallopt)).  The default threshold between "small" and "large" is 128 *kilobytes*; you allocated 0x6400000 bytes = 100 *megabytes*, which is, obviously, much larger.  The line of your mappings dump reading

```
0xb19fd000 0xb7dfe000 rw-p  mapped
```

is exactly one page larger than what you asked for - the discrepancy is due to `malloc` taking some extra space for its own bookkeeping information.

The `[heap]` segment appears when you call `printf` because - again, this is a quirk of glibc - the very first time you do anything with `stdout`, some memory gets allocated internally, using `malloc`.  That allocation is *smaller* than 128kB so it gets put in the `sbrk` region and there you are.

(Depending on what kind of "heap spray" attack you are trying to simulate, either you don't care that your 100MB wound up in its own `mmap` allocation because you're just trying to cover enough of the overall address space that a wild pointer has a decent chance of pointing in there, or you need to allocate a large number of *small* objects, each the same size as some key piece of data in the vulnerable application, so that you have a decent chance of getting your allocations mixed up with the application's.)

Answer (score 2):

`HeapBuf` resides on stack just like any other `int`s, `long`s, `char`s you have in your code because *the pointer itself* is merely a number. But *the memory it points to* is indeed allocated on the heap.

Comment: There's not even a heap segment in the process. Also I checked the contents of HeapBuf and they're in the address range of the [stack] map. I can provide proof if you want.

Comment: glibc's implementation of `malloc` will use `mmap` directly for allocations this large.  The only map entry that appears to be big enough for this allocation is `0x989fd000 0xb7dfe000 rw-p  mapped`.  It is NOT on the stack; the stack is far too small.

Comment: Ok, thank you @zwol, this actually answers my question.

Comment: @Cryptomancer OK, I'll write up a more thorough explanation based on the information you added.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot duplicate OP's results. However, I'm running on an x86-64 kernel and 64-bit binaries, unlike OP.

Here is a small test program, **test.c**:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void self_maps(void)
{
    FILE *in;
    int   c;

    in = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    if (!in)
        return;

    /* Let the C library handle the buffering. */
    while ((c = getc(in)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);

    fclose(in);
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t NOPSize = 960;
    size_t ShellcodeSize = 64;
    size_t PayloadSize = NOPSize + ShellcodeSize;
    size_t BufferSize = 0x6400000;
    size_t i;

    char Payload[PayloadSize];
    char *HeapBuf;

    HeapBuf = malloc(BufferSize);
    if (!HeapBuf) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Payload = %p\n", (void *)Payload);
    printf("HeapBuf = %p\n", (void *)HeapBuf);

    for (i = 0; i < NOPSize; i++)
        Payload[i] = '\x90';

    for (i = NOPSize; i < PayloadSize; i++)
        Payload[i] = '\x41';

    for (i = 0; i < BufferSize; i++)
        HeapBuf[i] = Payload[i % PayloadSize];

    printf("\n");
    self_maps();

    free(HeapBuf);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If I compile and run it using

```
gcc -Wall -O2 test.c -o test

./test
```

I get output

```
Payload = 0x7fff3122b6b0
HeapBuf = 0x7f378806a010

00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 4587700                /.../test
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:07 4587700                /.../test
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:07 4587700                /.../test
022c3000-022e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                      [heap]
7f378806a000-7f378e46b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f378e46b000-7f378e62a000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1966262        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f378e62a000-7f378e82a000 ---p 001bf000 08:05 1966262        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f378e82a000-7f378e82e000 r--p 001bf000 08:05 1966262        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f378e82e000-7f378e830000 rw-p 001c3000 08:05 1966262        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f378e830000-7f378e834000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f378e834000-7f378e85a000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 1966245        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f378ea2c000-7f378ea2f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f378ea57000-7f378ea59000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f378ea59000-7f378ea5a000 r--p 00025000 08:05 1966245        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f378ea5a000-7f378ea5b000 rw-p 00026000 08:05 1966245        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f378ea5b000-7f378ea5c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff3120c000-7fff3122d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0              [stack]
7fff3126c000-7fff3126e000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0              [vvar]
7fff3126e000-7fff31270000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0              [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0      [vsyscall]
```

Because the version of the GNU C library I'm using uses memory mapping for allocations larger than 130 kB or so, `HeapBuf` is in a mapping of its own:

```
7f378806a000-7f378e46b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```